# Add controller option is missing in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual studio 2015 and after opening an existing project, I am not able to see the add controller option while right clicking on the Controller Folder. Please help.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38369200/1252036) helped me to resolve the same problem

Answer (score 10):

- Open VS2015=>TOOLS=>Customize
- Select Commands
- Select Context menu
- Select Project and Solution Context Menus|Folder|Add
- Check that 'Controller' appears.
- **IMPORTANT - Move up Controller item to the top.**

Comment: Following this made the Controller option appear for me but clicking the controller option doesn't actually do anything!

Comment: Same here, I now have the option to add a controller which is invisible, inaudible, tasteless and odourless. I tried reaching out with my feelings, but even the force couldn't detect it. I would have preferred a chocolate teapot. At least I could console myself with confectionery therapy.

Comment: I was under the impression these context options for **Controller** or **Views** appear depending on the NuGet packages you have installed in **project.json**, specifically Entity Framework packages in conjunction with the **Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc** package. I noticed this when building my project up from an empty template and then gradually adding packages I needed. At some point, the Controller and Views context menu items seemed to be made available.

Comment: Just did a test from an Empty Project and it was only after adding the following packages to project.json that the Controller and View context menu items appeared: EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final", EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final", "Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc1-final"

Comment: @thudbutt I'm having the same issue in VS 2017 - how did you fix it?

Comment: @niico Afraid I didn't, I think I was using an RC version and I put it down to that.

Comment: @thudbutt thanks - doing a full re-install here (only did a complete machine wipe 2 weeks ago).

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem on my ASP.NET project in VS2015. I solved by installing **Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools**.
It doesn't appear in NuGet Manager so you have to install with Package Manager Console: `Install-Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools -Version 1.0.0-preview2-final -Pre`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. After messing around with the GUID numbers and trying to reinstall, the answer came down to updating Visual Studio 2015.

Go to Tools > Extensions and Updates > Updates (Tab on the left) > Visual Studio.

It was around 3 Gigs.

Hope this helps

Comment: I had the issue and updated "github extension" in "Go to Tools > Extensions and Updates > Updates".

After restarting VS2015, the add controller menu item was back.

I guess updating any Extensions will do.

Answer (score 3):

OK, this was driving me up the wall so I created a default MVC project to see what on earth I was missing, would you like to know??
Here is the answer.

In project.json under dependencies, please add:

```
"Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
```

Or which ever version is now available. Then right click your folders for views etc and the menu options appear!

Answer (score 1):

From [Chris Zhao on asp.net][1]: You could consider uninstalling VS 2015, and reinstall it again,and check whether "Web Developer tools" is selected [go into Custom during the installation to be sure it is checked.

I did this and it enabled the add controller option.

Answer (score 1):

Right Click on Add Reference --> ManageNugetPackage --> Search for Microsoft ASPNET.MVC and Install that package. Then come back to project and right-click on controller folder and see ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following command in the NuGet console to install the package.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc -Pre
```

Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following 2 dependencies in project.json worked for me to get Add controller and view context menus as well as the scaffolding. I have VS 2015 with Update 3.

Under dependencies -

```
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "imports": [
    "portable-net45+win8"
  ]
},
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
```

And under Tools section:

```
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "imports": [
    "portable-net45+win8"
  ]
}
```

Comment: it works for me after update "vs 2015 update 3"  and I don't know, is update important or not?

Comment: I am also not sure of that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have recently cleaned all the files in your solution then it may just be a matter of re-building the solution, to restore your NuGet packages.

Answer (score 0):

I followed every step and nothing worked. so the problem is definitely related to the code generators, but what I had to do is include booth codeGenerator.MVC and CodeGeneration.Tools in the dependencies section

```
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
  "type": "build",
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
}
```

And the following in the tools section

```
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
enter code here
```

**FYI:** No need to follow the steps TOOLS=>Customize, once the code generator is added the Controller will appear immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I closed and re-opened Visual Studio and then the issue solved.