# Where is Controller Scafolding in .Net Core 1.0.0 with Visual Studio Update 3

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I'm using the latest ASP.net Core bits (1.0.0-preview2-final with Visual Studio Update 3) and the Add > New Scafolded Item seems to have gone for the 'Web Application' template.

It was there in RC2.

I've seen [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38108163/view-scaffold-templates-in-asp-net-core/38240517#38240517) saying that you need to add following line in project.json under dependencies.

```
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
```

Also, add following under tools

```
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
```

If I do this, it does expose the UI, but I get "Version for package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools' could not be resolved" when I click OK.

Ideas / workarounds?

PS: Please do not mark this as a duplicate without ensuring that answer you are referring to for the duplicate is the very latest version of .net core, 1.0.0-preview2-final (released 27th June 2016).

Answer (score 0):

Check that your global.json is at the correct version:

```
"version": "1.0.0-preview2-003121"
```

Comment: Thanks - which entry is this the version for, or is it all three of them?

Comment: It is not for any entry in project.json, but is for the version in global.json which is stored in the same directory as *.sln file.