# Adding a NEW custom controller scaffold in ASP.Net Core 2

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

The question [Custom scaffold templates in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38382954/custom-scaffold-templates-in-asp-net-core)
 provides describes how to customize scaffolding templates. As per the comments in the accepted answer, how do you register a new scaffolder so that it appears in the Add=>controller context menu options?