# Using ASP.net MVC 5 scaffolding in ASP.net Core MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

In MVC 5, when you scaffold a View, Create, with a model - in order to build a form that will be bound to the model - the scaffolder in MVC 5 used columns (col-md-10 and col-md-2) to put labels to the left of textboxes:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Username, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", autocomplete = "off" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

In Core MVC 2, all labels are above text boxes - which is super space inefficient:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Email" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

I could edit all of this by hand but this defeats the object of scaffolding and will take a long time.

Is there any way to get the scaffolder to use the previous col type of layout - or are there any third party options?

I can find nothing in Google. Thanks.

Comment: Well, you can always create your own scaffolding using T4 templates, but man if that isn't the most obtuse waste of time ever. It takes literally no time to build out a form like this by hand. Scaffolding is not intended to write all your code for you; it's *expected* that you'll be changing it.

Comment: If you're building a lot of forms (I am) doing a repetitive change again and again is something to be avoided (DRY) - in MVC 5 it made a lot more sense. Who wants to have labels above text boxes?! Gotta love the unexplained drive by down vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scaffolding templates are pretty easy to edit to your tastes.

In Asp.Net Core MVC 2 the templates are now cshtml rather than t4.

You simply copy the templates into your project [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38382954/custom-scaffold-templates-in-asp-net-core), then the next time you run the scaffolder it'll use your templates rather than the default templates.

Comment: Thanks though the path they list doesn't exist (packages folder doesn't contain Microsoft.VisualStudio...... folder). Has this been changed?

Comment: I'm using VS2017 and mine are here: C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.visualstudio.web.codegenerators.mvc\2.0.3\Templates

Comment: If you can't find them try searching for MvcControllerWithContext.cshtml - that's a file in one of the template folders, you should then be able to find the parent Templates directory from that.