# Why Visual Studio automatically creates ApiController with all async methods? How to create ApiController with sync methods in it?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-core-webapi, visual-studio-2019, synchronous

I have created a asp.net core webapi controller named **StudentsController.cs** using the functionality provided by Visual Studio which is **API Controller with actions,using Entity Framework**. It implements all the controller methods with return type `async Task<ActionResult<>>` which is asynchronous method implementation and it is auto generated by Visual Studio

Question is **Why it creates all the methods async by its own and how can I create all the methods synchronously using the same auto generate feature of Visual Studio?**

**async example of controller**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Students.Models;

namespace Students.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class StudentsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly StudentContext _context;

        public StudentsController(StudentContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/Students
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Student>>> GetStudents()
        {
            return await _context.Students.Include(d => d.Department).ToListAsync();
        }

        // GET: api/Students/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Student>> GetStudent(int id)
        {
            var student = await _context.Students.Include(d => d.Department).FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.SId == id);

            if (student == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return student;
        }

        // PUT: api/Students/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD.
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutStudent(int id, Student student)
        {
            if (id != student.SId)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            _context.Departments.Update(student.Department);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            _context.Entry(student).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!StudentExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return Ok();
        }
        //[HttpPut]
        //public async Task<IActionResult> PutStudent(Student student)
        //{

        //    _context.Departments.Update(student.Department);
        //    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        //    _context.Entry(student).State = EntityState.Modified;

        //    try
        //    {
        //        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        //    }
        //    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        //    {
        //        if (!StudentExists(student.SId))
        //        {
        //            return NotFound();
        //        }
        //        else
        //        {
        //            throw;
        //        }
        //    }

        //    return Ok();
        //}

        // POST: api/Students
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD.
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Student>> PostStudent(Student student)
        {
            _context.Students.Add(student);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetStudent", new { id = student.SId }, student);
        }


        [HttpPost]
        [Route("StudentList")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Student>> PostStudentList([FromBody] List<Student> student)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (Student s in student)
                {
                    _context.Students.Add(s);
                }
                _context.SaveChanges();
                return CreatedAtAction("GetStudents", student, _context.Students.Include(d => d.Department));
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }

        // DELETE: api/Students/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Student>> DeleteStudent(int id)
        {
            var student = await _context.Students.FindAsync(id);
            if (student == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.Students.Remove(student);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return student;
        }

        private bool StudentExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Students.Any(e => e.SId == id);
        }
    }
}
```

**sync example of controller**

````
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using CourseCRUD.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace CourseCRUD.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class SubjectController : Controller
    {
        private readonly CourseContext _context;

        public SubjectController(CourseContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        // GET:api/subject
        public IActionResult GetSubjects()
        {
            try
            {
                var subjects = _context.subjects.ToList();
                return Ok(subjects);
            }
            catch
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult AddSubject([FromBody]Subject subject)
        {

            try
            {
                _context.subjects.Add(subject);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                return CreatedAtAction("GetSubjets", subject);
            }
            catch
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
      public IActionResult GetSuject(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                var subject = _context.subjects.Find(id);
                return Ok(subject);
            }
            catch
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }

        [HttpPut("id")]

        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public IActionResult UpdateSubject(int id, Subject subject)
        {
            if (id != subject.SubjectId)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            _context.Entry(subject).State = EntityState.Modified;
            try
            {
                _context.SaveChanges();
                return Ok(subject);
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!SubjectDetailExist(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

        }

        private bool SubjectDetailExist(int id)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public IActionResult DeleteSubject(int id)
        {
            var result = _context.subjects.Find(id);
            if (result == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.subjects.Remove(result);

            try
            {
                _context.SaveChanges();
                return Ok(result);
            }
            catch
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }

    }
}```
````

Comment: Probably because most web applications use database calls, calls to other services, etc. so it allows a server to handle more requests if you use async calls (since you're not blocking a thread while waiting for a response from the database, etc.). That would be my guess. Why do you want to make all of your methods sync?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer and show how can I create all methods synchronously as given in example of sync controller using the same auto code generate feature of Visual Studio?**And** I want to create all sync because this implementation is part of my training as trainee in a company and I have been asked to differentiate these both types of implementation

Comment: Again: I'm simply guessing why they are all _async_. I have no idea how you can do that, and I don't really understand _why_ you want to.

Comment: *"Why it creates all the methods async"* - Because It's Better™

Comment: If you've been given a task to differentiate two types of controllers, then just create an `aysnc` and create a copy you can change it into `sync`.... why would you make more work for yourself to create everything twice?

Answer (score 0):

it's a long time since I did anything with t4 templates so a bit rusty but you should perhaps start here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates?view=vs-2019

You specify templates in text files and use rules to generate the required code.

```
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Xml" #>
<#
 System.Xml.XmlDocument configurationData = ...; // Read a data file here.
#>
namespace Fabrikam.<#= configurationData.SelectSingleNode("jobName").Value #>
{
  ... // More code here.
}
```

Depending on the values in the XML file, the generated .cs file would resemble the following:

```
namespace Fabrikam.FirstJob
{
  ... // More code here.
}
```

---

I don't know if controller scaffolding uses t4 templates but it wouldn't suprise me.. or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

The `async` actions are generated by templates  of scaffolding which locates in path similar to  `C:\ProgramFiles\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.visualstudio.web.codegenerators.mvc\2.0.3\Templates`

You could change the template manually.Refer to
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39503291/10158551