# ASP.net core find model.primary_key_field_name in custom scaffolding

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-scaffolding

I have an asp.net core MVC project I am creating custom scaffolding template files

I am following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38382954/custom-scaffold-templates-in-asp-net-core#answer-39503291) to add custom scaffolding template pages

on `Details` page I want o add link to `Listing`, `Edit` and `Delete` page as below

```
@using System.Linq
@@model @Model.ViewDataTypeName

@:    <div class="card-body py-2">
@:        <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@@Model.pkName" class="float-right btn-floating btn-sm btn-danger m-0" title="Delete @Model.ViewDataTypeShortName Record"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>    
@:        <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@@Model.pkName" class="float-right btn-floating btn-sm btn-warning m-0 mr-2" title="Edit @Model.ViewDataTypeShortName Record"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>   
@:        <a asp-action="Index" class="float-right btn-floating btn-sm btn-info m-0 mr-2" title="Back to @Model.ViewDataTypeShortName listing page"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></a>    
@:        <h4 class="mb-2 mb-sm-0 pt-1">@Model.ViewDataTypeShortName Details</h4>
@:    </div>
```

Notice  `asp-route-id="@@Model.pkName"` in above example, Actualloy here I need to put primaryKey field name dynamically, `@@Model.pkName` is not a valid property but I just wanted to show something here.

Comment: Hi @alamnaryab, so how do you design your model and what is your DbContext like?

Comment: I am using codefirst approach with `ApplicationDbContext`, some models primary keys are named `ID`, `recId`, `id` etc

Comment: Hi @alamnaryab, It is better for you to show us what do you change for the custom scaffolding template and your model design. By default scaffolding, it will display the primary key on `asp-route-id`.

Comment: Dear @Rena default scaffolding was having only `<h3>@Model.ViewName</h3>` while I replaced with content displayed in `div.card-body`, in above code  `@@model.pkName` is throwing error, I want it to display `model.id`,`model.recID`,`model.whatever_is_primarykey_field_name`