# View scaffolding fails in Visual Studio 2015 for ASP.NETCore MVC

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I have Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition Update 3 running on Windows 8.1. I also have the latest .NET Core 1.1 installed.

I couldn't scaffold a new Controller so found this [thread](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/290) on github, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38108163/view-scaffold-templates-in-asp-net-core/38240517#38240517) one on SO and after adding these 2 -

- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools

in project.json it worked fine. Before adding the above 2 the Microsoft.NETCore.App version was 1.0.1 but the above Tools package requires version to be 1.1.0 so I modified the Microsoft.NETCore.App to be 1.1.0. 
I had to also upgrade/restore all Nuget packages to target this update.
After this I was able to scaffold Controllers in the project.

Now, I am trying to add a new View to my project, I see this scaffolding error -

[image]

Any workarounds/ideas that I can try to get it to work? Or could this be a bug with ASP.NET Core tooling in VS 2015?

I could probably go ahead by adding files manually and use Visual Studio Code, but I want to see if this issue can be resolved and I can stick to Visual Studio.

EDIT: Adding a section of my project.json file

```js
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.1.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
      "type": "build"
    }
    },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
       ]
     }
    },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win81-x64": {}
  }
  }
```

Comment: adding controller you can choose option using ef and generate views

Comment: @Alex I don't want to use EF as I'm trying to get data from a service. I tried this anyway and it did work, only Add View seems to fail.

Comment: have you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to update your Visual Studio 2015 Tooling
such from https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core
Make sure you selected the current tab not LTS. Then use nuget to update all your project dependency.
Hope this helps

Comment: I had this tooling update already before I created the ASP.NET Core project

Comment: Yes, I still am facing the same issue

Comment: Can you post your project .json file