# "Add View" context menu From Controller Class View in VS2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I'm creating my newest project in ASP.NET CORE inside Visual Studio 2015.

But I have noticed that I am missing a few menus in the context menu when INSIDE a controller class view. In VS2013 I used to be able to create a View Method (Ie:)

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

I used to be able to right click on Index() and then click "Add View", but this seems to be missing in VS 2015?

Comment: Yes we do not have this option in ASP.NET CORE inside Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add controller option is missing in Visual Studio 2015](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32901637/add-controller-option-is-missing-in-visual-studio-2015)